# Истовый и неистовый

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, выбор-слов

**Истовый** — страстно убежденный в чем-то, считающий это истиной, ревностно следующий своим убеждениям.
**Неистовый** — это бурно проявляющий свои чувства.

Почему «неистовый» отрицает слово «истовый»? Это главный вопрос.
А также: почему иногда они взаимозаменяемы?

*Гудящий, почти осязаемый кожей **неистовый** жар молитв.* (Или истовый?)

*Здесь самозабвение соборности, когда **истовый** пыл превращает торгующих в молящихся.* (Или неистовый?)

Comment: Надо же, я тоже собиралась задать этот вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      Почему «неистовый» отрицает слово «истовый»?
```

Изначально действительно отрицало: истовый - от "истый" - "истинный, подлинный, настоящий", неистовый (употребляется с 11 века)-"вышедший из себя, не похожий на себя",т.е. ненастоящий, в современном значении осталось от него  "несдержанный в проявлении своих чувств,исступлённо жестокий"(Неистовый Аввакум, неистовый Виссарион, когда говорят об их нетерпимости к противникам и чужим мнениям).

А сближаться значения стали, когда слово стало употребляться в переносном  значении "усердный, ревностный", от него в современном - "необычайно сильный". У нас усердных любят, отрицательная контаминация ушла.

```
      Почему иногда они взаимозаменяемы?
```

«Гудящий, почти осязаемый кожей неистовый жар молитв»- совр. знач.необычайно сильный, а в прежнем значении "вышедший из себя, сильный до ненастоящего, чрезмерного". (Или истовый, т.е. усердный, ревностный, но тоже чрезвычайно)Вот и получается, что антонимы стали синонимами.

"Здесь самозабвение соборности, когда истовый (ревностный)пыл превращает торгующих в молящихся". (Или неистовый - необычайно сильный, чрезмерный)

Первоначальное значение даёт намёк на то, что изначально истинным чувством было настоящее, от себя, от сердца, а что сверх нормы, чрезвычайно, то не истинное, ненастоящее, иногда лицемерное. Мне это изначальное близко.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, очень интересное мнение.

Comment: >Гудящий, почти осязаемый кожей **неистовый жар молитв, жалоб и клятв** колеблется в раскаленном воздухе, распирает его и уносится ввысь – по назначению. Ведь все эти люди – все без исключения – собрались здесь с единственной целью: прославления Создателя. И каждый славит его, как умеет, насколько хватает ватт собственной души: на своем языке, на свой манер, **по своему понятию.**

Показан религиозный фанатизм в чистом виде. Где же здесь сближение  *неистовства* с *истовостью*?? Ну разве только в разгоряченном мозгу фанатиков-верующих, вошедших в крайнюю степень экстаза. Тогда все понятно.

Comment: Мне как раз в этом сближение и видится: истово молятся - усердно, неистово - чрезмерно ревностно, фанатично. Т.е. сближаются прямое и переносное значения.

Comment: Это Битов придумал лет пятнадцать назад :  
>...Какая же толерантность, когда у нас “истовый” и “неистовый” — это одно слово? И “терпимость” и “нетерпимость” — антиподы! — тоже, в общем-то, одно слово. Что же это за терпимость, когда не понимаю, а терплю... Вот — терплю.

Но частное мнение одного писателя - отнюдь не закон для русского языка. Слова разные и давайте оставим *неистовую веру* для сумасшедших и одержимых, а *истовую* - редким благоразумным подвижникам.

Answer (score 2):

Истовый - соблюдаемый по всем правилам и традициям; неистовый - чрезмерный, малоконтролируемый сознанием (т.е. наперекор всем обычаям и общественным приличиям). Взаимозамена невозможна, а если она происходит - это явная ошибка автора текста. Пример нормальных словоприменений, которые нам всем хорошо известны и понятны :

> Н. И. Голицына. Воспоминания о польском восстании 1830-1831 (1837)
> 13/25 августа я проехала заставу старой столицы и **истово перекрестилась**, возблагодарив Господа за то, что возвратилась к родительскому очагу вопреки всем бунтам, болезням, врагам и революциям, преследовавшим меня.
>
> Н. А. Дурова. Кавалерист-девица (1835)
> Прошед еще с полверсты, я увидела наконец нечто черное, приближающееся ко мне и **кричащее неистово.**

Comment: Как правильно: истовое служение вере или неистовое служение вере?

Comment: В двух выражениях - разные смыслы! Первое означает правильный путь, второе - неправильный. *Неистовое служение* - похоже на сектанство, заблуждение...

Comment: Я нашла статью, где высказывается мнение о том, что изначально противоположное значение у этих слов стало сближаться, при этом они часто (хотя и не всегда)в большей степени обозначают  общее усердие и рвение, чем соответствуют  или не соответствуют  истине. http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=14.85

Comment: Я считаю подобный взгляд (статья по ссылке) слишком надуманным. Личной фантазией автора, которому хочется так предполагать. Да еще новую категорию слов ввести! Нет, не согласен. Слова совершенно разные.

Comment: Сравниваем :  
>**ИСТОВЫЙ** 
прил. 1) а) Такой, как подобает; надлежащий, настоящий, истинный. б) Неуклонно следующий правилам, соблюдающий традиции; ревностный. в) Совершаемый с большим рвением, крайне усердно. 2) Чинный, степенный; торжественный. 
>**НЕИСТОВЫЙ** 
прил. 1) Находящийся в состоянии неистовства, исступления; безудержный, необузданный. 2) Выражающий необузданность, исступление. 3) Необычайно сильный.

Comment: Мне кажется, что фактическое употребление этих слов не совпадает со словарной статьей. Истовый  обозначает страстную праведность, а неистовый - такое же страстное всё остальное, в том числе (в некоторых случаях) и правильную веру.

Comment: "Неистовая правильная" вера? Сектанство и фанатизм. Целые государства уже охвачены подобным *неистовством*, которое *истовостью* называть не следует ни в коем случае.  
...Как в словаре Ефремовой написано, так слова и употребляются. Без исключений.

Answer (score 0):

С учетом полученных ответов можно предположить следующее.

1) Одним из значений слова "истовый" является "такой, какой должен быть". Соответственно, «неистовый» – это неправильный, не такой, как полагается.

2) Возможно, что значение излишнего рвения и  страстной эмоциональности вторичны для обоих слов, и на этой почве и произошло их сближение.

3) В настоящее время «истовый и неистовый»  близки по значению, но сочетаемость у них, как правило,  разная.  Обычно по отношению к вере, убеждениям они действительно взаимозаменяемы: истовая вера, неистовая вера.

4) Примечание: одновременно со словом «истовый» существовало  прилагательное «истый», а также образованное от него существительное «истина», которые в большей степени соответствуют современному значению «истинный».

Answer (score 0):

**ИСТОВЫЙ** прил.
1. а) Такой, как подобает; надлежащий, настоящий, истинный.
б) Неуклонно следующий правилам, соблюдающий традиции; ревностный.
в) Совершаемый с большим рвением, крайне усердно.

2) Чинный, степенный; торжественный.

**НЕИСТОВЫЙ** прил.
1. Находящийся в состоянии неистовства, исступления; безудержный, необузданный.
2. Выражающий необузданность, исступление.
3. Необычайно сильный.

Итак, в данном случае общей мерой здесь является чрезмерное усилие, усердие, сила, категоричное проявление силового действия, усилия; в случае с *истовым* — намеренно и целенаправленно, в случае с *неистовым* — необузданно, неконтролируемо.
И там, и там — общим является выход энергии, большого количества силы. А поскольку энергия является интуитивно, негласно основным и приоритетным проявлением множества качеств, то и коннотация прошла именно по этому признаку.

Т.е. формально это может быть неверно — с точки зрения сухого изолированного академического знания. Но формируют язык не только учёные и реформы, но и народ, как носитель и преобразователь. И часто реформы подстраиваются под диалект того или иного народа, а народ улавливает их интуитивно, по общим чертам, "кантуя" слова от села к селу, от культуры к культуре.
Так и получилось, что *истовый* и *неистовый* в простонародье имеют схожие значения — по признаку выброса большой силы.